fabric.js-How to select the inside rectangle?
I have two rectangles. The red one seems to be inside the green one. I want to click the red one, but the mouse:down handler returns the options.target as the green one. How can I solve this problem?


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: "green",
    strokeWidth: 1, 
    fill:"transparent",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    hasControls:false,
    hasBorders:false
  });

  var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 120,
    top: 120,
    stroke: "red",
    strokeWidth: 1, 
    fill:"transparent",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    hasControls:false,
    hasBorders:false
  });
canvas.add(rect1)
canvas.add(rect2);

canvas.on("mouse:down",function(options){
    console.log("the target is:", options?.target?.stroke);
});
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@5.3.0/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300"></canvas>
</body>

</html>



Thanks.

According to the documentation, you can use the bringToFront command to change its order. This command brings the object to the top (first position) of the stacking order. However, with any mouse event, the parent(green) rectangle goes to the first position of the stack again since it orders them automatically in each event. Therefore, the red one still stays on the back of it and when you click on the red rectangle, the green one displays on the event data.
To prevent automatic ordering, need to set the preserveObjectStacking property to true. I also added some comment lines in the code to explain:


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
// Set preserveObjectStacking to true to prevent changing stack order on mouse events
canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true;

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  stroke: 'green',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fill: 'transparent',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  hasControls: false,
  hasBorders: false,
});

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 120,
  top: 120,
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 1,
  fill: 'transparent',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  hasControls: false,
  hasBorders: false,
});
canvas.add(rect1);
canvas.add(rect2);

// Bring the object to the top of the stacking order
canvas.bringToFront(rect2);

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
  console.log('the target is:', options?.target?.stroke);
});
<html>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@5.3.0/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="300"></canvas>
</body>

</html>



I also created a DEMO LINK for you to review and test it easily
Hope, it's clear and helpful
